# Existence and uniqueness of the central value of a probability measure by Doob.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Let $\mu$ be a one-dimensional probability measure. The *central value* $\gamma = \gamma(\mu)$ is defined by J.L. Doob to be the real number $\gamma$ such that 
$$\int_{R^1} \arctan(x-\gamma) \mu(dx)=0.$$ 
The existence and the uniqueness of $\gamma$ follow from the fact that for $x$ fixed, $\arctan(x-\gamma)$ decreases strictly and continuously from $\pi/2$ to $-\pi/2$ as $\gamma$ moves from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

This is an excerpt from Ito's Stochastic Processes. I don't follow the existence and uniqueness argument. $x$ itself is random here so how tdoes the above properties of $\arctan(x-\gamma)$ guarantee the existence and uniqueness of such $\gamma$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

1. Using the dominated convergence theorem show that the mapping $$\gamma \mapsto F(\gamma) := \int_{\mathbb{R}} \arctan(x-\gamma) \, \mu(dx)$$ is continuous.
2. Conclude from the fact that $y \mapsto \arctan(y)$ is strictly increasing that $\gamma \mapsto F(\gamma)$ is strictly increasing.
3. Use the dominated convergence theorem to show that $$\lim_{\gamma \to \infty} F(\gamma) = - \frac{\pi}{2} \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{\gamma \to -\infty} F(\gamma) = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$
4. Conclude.